# Layout align center under ConstraintLayout in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: android, layout, alignment, center, android-constraintlayout

In Android Studio 2.3.1 built on 2017 April 1. I could not center my 2nd LinearLayout over my 1st LinearLayout.

Here is my second layout:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to Component Tree > RIGHT CLICK on my2ndlayout

> choose "Center Horizontally" and "Center Vertically" !!

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on button in design view and find for Constraint Layout

options under this option you will get Infer Constraint option click on that . now you can drag it to centre manually and the code will be generate in your xml automatically.